how to get a file path from assets folder with just knowing a string in it's name in angular 17
i have a file with a name main-5WAPJH7.js in a child project's folder whose dist is contained in assets folder of my another project. I want to load this file in a component so that the child project runs in that component. But the string after main- keeps on changing when dist folder is created. I want to get the path of this file using just 'main'.
This is the code that loads scripts:-
const scripts = [
'assets/projects/observability/main-5WAPJFH7.js'
];
styles.forEach(styleUrl => {
  const link = this.renderer.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = styleUrl;
  this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, link);
});


In package.json, scripts object, add a postbuild and write a script that renames the main.js by removing the hash.
This is the simplest solution to your problem.
Else when you programatically copy the generated script, remove the hash and place it on the assets folder.

Can you please give an example of a script that can change a file name of a file being created using ng build command like main.ts ??

@jiteshvijay You can check this article

@jiteshvijay Run this script during postbuild in the project that generates this main.ts file that you want to reference.
